# What does 尿尿 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word, meaning

I was scrolling down on YouTube comments until someone wrote 老师好。新年快乐。给尿尿了。A person answered 新年快乐，不说给尿尿，哈哈.

I look it up but it said that 尿尿 means piss. Is that true?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the source?

Comment: sounds like a teasing joke. "Hi, Sir, happy new year! time to (wake up and ) go piss"

Comment: So, is that what the person is saying. However, he wrote 给 does that mean giving you urine, my piss or since it's new years ( here is my pee). This is the weirdest thing I ever heard.

Comment: @TherissaToussaint, That's why I've asked you to provide the source. 给 could be a typo. Without the actual context, the intended character could be 该， which is sometimes easily typed as 给 in Pinyin Input method. So the person who responded to that comment put: 不说给尿尿, which purposely pointed out that typo. Well, 该尿尿了 means it's right time to piss. I think that person was trying to say a joke here.

Comment: I provided the source but it's the same thing I wrote. So 该 ->happy New year's. should go pee

Comment: It looks like they’re correcting an earlier comment.

Comment: @TherissaToussaint 该 means *should*. What's that YouTube video about? The person who put 给尿尿了 might not be a native speaker. Well, the response from HSK seemed to be a teacher who was trying to point out that error. 给尿尿了 is not a right expression.

Comment: looks lik a typo or something, 'cause the dialog doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true. But I think that comment is actually pretty strange. haha